# Google Custom Login Page: Client Login Deprecated

Tags: authentication, client, google-apps

I have been successfully able to run a Custom Login Page for Google Apps until today. I used to use Client for the Google Apps Provisioning service. using which we could send email (username) and password as parameters and obtain the authentication token.

With OAuth2 (as per Google we need to upgrade to OAuth2 starting 20th April, 2015) I can't find a solution! There's no way I can send/ check if a username/ password pair is correct.

Comment: There is nothing you can do.. its deprecated and you MUST migrate to OAuth type of authentication. With OAuth , you don't send username and password to the server and its much better way of authentication / authorization..

Comment: That's correct: there is no way and you need to implement an alternative solution using OAuth 2.0. If this has become an urgent issue for you today, it's because you've ignored Google's notifications about the deprecation of client login for the last 3 (!) years.

Comment: Robby,
Sure, I agree. It was a lapse from my side and I apologize for that. Currently I'm temporarily putting on Google's default login while I'm trying to fix this.

@AbdelRaoof: 
I also agree OAuth is better but how can I achieve a custom login page using OAuth since OAuth never accepts/ validates username/ password pair but works purely on request & access tokens. Can I assume making Custom Login Pages is not possible going forward?

Comment: You need SAML for custom login page.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: Definitely, eventually I'm using SAML (without which Google will not even accept login done by my 3rd party site as a legitimate one). Just before sending SAML Response, I'm checking if the username/ password pair is correct and that's where I can't find an alternative to Client for Google Apps Provisioning Service. Please help with an alternative, if possible.

Comment: Please can someone help me? Can I assume there's no way to send username/ password as a parameter to some Google Service so that I could atleast validate whether they are correct? Only then Custom Login Page can be possible. Currently, there's no way to achieve custom login page via OAuth, seems like. Is that correct? Could someone confirm?

Comment: @Rahul when you use SAML, you should keep your own user database. Why sending it to google for validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way now to do what you want. You could use SAML2 and then use Google as the source IDP via OpenID but you would end seeing the Google Login page again. It seems that you are trying to hide the fact that it is a Google shop.

SAML2 auth lets you design your own login screen but requires that you use your own user database.