# Using Google as the Source IDP

Tags: google-apps, identity

Is there a way of passing username/ password to Google Apps IDP and get a response as to whether a username/ password pair is correct?

I know I can use OAuth for authorization and access user data but note that I want to check if his credentials itself are valid. OAuth for sure will not work for me. I need a way to directly query Google Apps' IDP particularly not to use it and access something else.

I wish to use this to customize the Google's standard login page itself. OAuth doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: _“I wish to use this to customize the Google's standard login page itself. OAuth doesn't allow me to do that.”_ – No, and for a good reason: Because the user has to be able to easily recognize it and its authenticity – otherwise they might easily get phished.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Custom Login Page: Client Login Deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739882/google-custom-login-page-client-login-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Google actively tries to prevent the scenario that you describe because it would mean that Google users hand over their Google credentials to your application, aka. phishing.

That precludes branding of the Google login pages as well since it would make it harder for users to verify that they actually type in their credentials on a login page provided by Google.

As said in the other answer, Google Signin with OpenID Connect (built on top of OAuth 2.0) is the standardized way to offer users login to your application with their Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Google (Apps) accounts can be used as an OpenID identity provider. By implementing your app as as a relying party, you could authenticate your users based on their Google accounts. Much like stackoverlow Google login: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html

With SAML SSO, Google acts as a relying party. While its possible to use provisioning API and clientLogin, this is not supported and is possibly against Google Apps ToS.